# Pattern alignment when using UILabel with groupTableViewBackgroundColor

Tags: iphone, cocoa-touch, uikit, uitableview

I have several UILabels in table cells, and I thought I could set them to be opaque and then setBackgroundColor:[UIColor groupTableViewBackgroundColor]] to make them have the table background. The grouped table background color in the UILabel isn't aligned with the table's background, though, so the lines are broken. Is there any way to fix that alignment? Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

You could set the background color to `[UIColor clearColor]`  and set the background of the table and/or table cells to be transparent as well.  This would have the cells appear to float on the background.  Some combination of that might work.  Might need to set the view's background to the `[UIColor groupTableViewBackgroundColor]` or something along those lines to get the effect you are looking for.

Comment: When I set the background color to `[UIColor clearColor]`, it looks like it's negating the effects of setting setting the UILabel to be opaque—it's having to blend the layers again, so scrolling is slower. I was hoping to avoid forcing the iPhone to blend the layers.

Comment: Hmmm...  I must not be understanding how you've got things laid out.  I have an app with the transparent table/cell/labels, so it looks like everything is floating on a background image (like the Amazon Kindle app) and it scrolls quite nicely.